# Optimizing in R with constraints

Tags: r, optimization

I have a function `f` of two variables which I want to minimize under the constraint `x[1]+x[2]=1`.
Here,

```
f <- function(x){
y <- 4*sin(x[1])+3*cos(x[2])
return(y) 
}
```

I have read here that `optim()` does the work, but how do I include my constraint?

Answer (score 1):

After adding the constraint `x[1] + x[2] = 1`, the function becomes an univariate function and you can rewrite it as the following:

```
f <- function(x){
  4*sin(x) + 3*cos(1-x)
}
```

`optimize()` can be used on one-dimensional optimization.

```
opt <- optimize(0, c(0, 10))
opt

# $minimum
# [1] 4.468871
# 
# $objective
# [1] -6.722745

curve(f, 0, 10)
with(opt, points(minimum, objective, col = "red", pch = 16))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but what I was really looking for was a way to directly specify constraints in the optimization algorithm. Sorry I didn't mention this in the question, which obviously allows a univariate solution as you described